# How to take sceenshots only when expect fails, using browser.takeScreenshot()

Tags: protractor

I want to capture screenshot whenever Spec fails here is the screenshot helper function I am using:

```
var fs = require('fs');
function screenshot(filename, path) {
 // within a test:
browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
    writeScreenShot(png, filename, path);
 });
}

function writeScreenShot(data, filename, path) {
var stream = fs.createWriteStream( path+ filename);
stream.write(new Buffer(data, 'base64'));
stream.end();
}
```

my Test:

```
describe('this is a sample test',function(){
 var testCaseName = this.getFullName();
 it('this is sample spec1',function(){
 // Test Steps
 expect(A).toBe(B);
 });
it('this is sample spec2',function(){
 // Test Steps
 expect(A).toBe(B);
 });
});
```

I want to take screenshot when ever my test Spec fails, how can I do that ? any suggestions ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit: **For Jasmine 2**, you can try https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter. This should be compatible with the latest version of Jasmine.

To install - `npm install protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter --save-dev` and register the report in your config file.

Then the option for capturing screenshots is:

```
var reporter = new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
   captureOnlyFailedSpecs: true
});
```

This may be the best option as I believe currentSpec() is no longer available for Jasmine 2.

---

**For Jasmine 1**, you have two options you could try. You can do something like this:

```
function screenshot(filename, path) {
  afterEach(function() {
     var passed = jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec.results().passed();
     if (!passed) {
       browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(png) {
         writeScreenShot(png, filename, path);
        });
      }
   });
}
```

Then in your spec:

```
describe('this is a sample test',function(){
 screenshot(filename, path);
```

Another option is https://github.com/jintoppy/protractor-html-screenshot-reporter. It handles taking screenshots for you and generates an html report. For taking screenshots on failures for that, you would do

```
new HtmlReporter({
    baseDirectory: '/tmp/screenshots'
    , takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: true
 });
```

Comment: jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec returns undefined.

Comment: hi @mallory I tried using HtmlReporter but it does not create any screenshots even if test fails.

Comment: hi @soniasharma, that may be due to the version of Jasmine used. I edited the post to reflect options for both Jasmine1 and Jasmine2.

Comment: Hi @Mallory, I am trying to use Jasmine2 screenshot Reporter but still it is not generating html report or screenshots : here is my config file:     `onPrepare: function() { var HtmlScreenshotReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter'); 
 var reporter =  new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
    dest: 'tests/test-results/screenshots',
    filename: 'my-report.html',
      captureOnlyFailedSpecs: true
   }); 
  },` what am i doing wrong here

Comment: Resolved the issue I am using `return browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(config) {var HtmlScreenshotReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter'); var reporter = new HtmlScreenshotReporter({ dest: 'tests/test-results/screenshots', filename: 'my-report.html', captureOnlyFailedSpecs: true }); jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter); }); ` and it Worked :) Thanks a Lot @Mallory

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture screenshots when expects fail, try this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine2-protractor-utils